# VBA Update column in SQL Server table with data from excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a excel workbook that pulls data into a table users can then fill in the missing dates in column 11. Column 1 is the unique identifier that matches the ID column in the SQL table. I want to create a macro that runs when the workbook is closed and will update the SQL table with the filled in dates, but I am struggling with the code. I have have tried two different things but neither seem to work.

Option 1:

```
 Private Sub tableupdate()

 Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
 Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim i As Long
 Dim vDB As Variant
 Dim ws As Worksheet

con.connectionstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=*********;User ID=clx_write;      Initial Catalog=DPEDataMartDBPrd01; Data Source=tcp:dscusnoramcloroxprd01.database.windows.net,1433;"

con.Open
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
Set ws = ActiveSheet

vDB = ws.Range("A4").CurrentRegion

For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbo].[all_load_control] set Driver_arr_dte = ' " & vDB(i, 2) & " '       WHERE mst_ship_num = ' " & vDB(i, 1) & " ' "
cmd.Execute
Next i

con.Close
Set con = Nothing


End Sub
```

option 2:

```
Private Sub uplodblanks()

Dim r, c, con, dstring
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim lRow
Dim ssql As String


con = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=********;User ID=clx_write; Initial   Catalog=DPEDataMartDBPrd01; Data Source=tcp:dscusnoramcloroxprd01.database.windows.net,1433;"

r = 1
c = 1
Worksheets("WTUpload").Calculate


lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), LookAt:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas,  SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
cn.Open con

i = 1
For i = 1 To lRow

ssql = "update dbo.cxu_all_load_control set driver_arr_dte = " &  CDate(Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11)) & " where mst_ship_num = " & CDbl(Sheets("WTUpload").Cells(i, 11)) & " ; "


cn.Execute ssql

Next i

cn.Close

End Sub
```

Any help as to why neither of these are working would be great

Comment: For **both** options: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: how does one parametrize queries?

Comment: Do some research - they are ***PLENTY*** of articles out there!

Comment: In Option 1 you are setting Driver_arr_dte to the value in column 2(B) where mst_ship_num is the value in Column 1(A). In Option 2 you are setting Driver_arr_dte to the value in column 11(K) where mst_ship_num is the value in the same Column 11(K) which makes no sense. Option 1 uses table [dbo].[all_load_control] and Option 2 uses dbo.cxu_all_load_control why different and which columns are correct ?

Comment: sorry. The driver_arr_dte I need is in column 11 of my excel spreadsheet

Comment: How are the 2 columns formatted in Excel; General, Number, Text, Date etc ? For the date column if is a true date (not text) what format are they displayed in dd/mm/yyyy , m/d/y , yyyy-mm-dd etc ? Dates can be a problem so it's important to know what you are dealing with. Also what data types are those 2 fields in the database table ?

Comment: Its custom date m/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Answer (score 0):

Replace the mydbConnect() function with you own method of getting a connection.

```vb
    Sub tableupdate2()

        Const COL_NUM As String = "A" 
        Const COL_DATE As String = "K" 
        Const TABLE As String = "dbo.all_load_control"

        ' define update sql
        Const SQL  As String = " UPDATE " & TABLE & _
                               " SET Driver_arr_dte = CAST(? AS DATETIME2) " & _
                               " WHERE mst_ship_num = ? "

        ' establish connection and create command object
        Dim con As Object, cmd As Object, sSQL As String
        Set con = mydbConnect() ' establish connection
        Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        With cmd
            .ActiveConnection = con
            .CommandText = SQL
            .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, 1, 20) '
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVarChar, 1, 50) ' adParamInput = 1
        End With

        ' prepare to get data from spreadsheet
        Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, iLast As Integer, iRow As Integer
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("WTUpload")
        iLast = ws.Range(COL_NUM & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim p1 As String, p2 As String, count As Long

        ' scan sheet and update db
        Debug.Print "Updates " & Now
        With cmd
            For iRow = 1 To iLast           
               p1 = Format(ws.Range(COL_DATE & iRow).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
               p2 = ws.Range(COL_NUM & iRow).Value
               If len(p2) > 0 Then
                    .Parameters(0).Value = p1
                    .Parameters(1).Value = p2
                    Debug.Print "Row ", iRow, "p1=" & p1, "P2=" & p2
                    .Execute
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With

        ' end
        MsgBox "Rows processed = " & count, vbInformation, "Updates Complete"
        con.Close
        Set con = Nothing
    End Sub

Edit - added connection and test code

    Function mydbConnect() As Object

        Dim sConStr As String

        sConStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Password=*********;User ID=clx_write;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=DPEDataMartDBPrd01;" & _
                  "Data Source=tcp:dscusnoramcloroxprd01.database.windows.net,1433;"

        Set mydbConnect = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        mydbConnect.Open sConStr

    End Function

    Sub test()

        Dim con As Object, rs As Object
        Set con = mydbConnect()
        Set rs = con.Execute("SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
        MsgBox rs.Fields(0), vbInformation, "Current Date/Time"

    End Sub
```

Comment: I added the connection inside the parenthesis and go an error saying: sub or function doesnt exist

Comment: @ndors I meant replace that whole Set con = mydbConnect()  line with the con lines in your question. I have edited my answer to include a mydbConnect() function with your connection string so leave the script as is and add the function to your code. I have also provide a connection test script for you.

Comment: on the scan sheet and update db portion of the code i get an error on the p2=ws.Range(COL_NUM & iRow).Value.

Comment: All of the fields in the sql table are nvarchar

Comment: sorry some of the columns are datetime2, such as driver_arr_dte, mst_ship_num is nvarchar(50). There is one column that is nvarchar(100)

Comment: in the section of the code that scans the sheet and uploads to the db I got an error saying conversion failed when converting the date and/or time from character string. When I hit debug it highlights the execute line of the code

Comment: @ndors There is a debug.print statement just before execute what did ii show ?

Comment: This shows up in the immediate window: Updates 2/12/2020 12:43:00 PM
Row            1            p1=           P2=Start Date
Row            2            p1=           P2=End Date
Row            4            p1=Driver Check In          P2=WH

Comment: so its all of the row s in column 11. Basically all of the rows in Driver Check In

Comment: row 4 has the column headers

Comment: Change the 1 on this line For iRow = 1 To iLast   to what ever row the first line of data is. Look like it might be 5 so it becomes For iRow = 5 To iLast

Comment: it runs but it still isnt updating the sql table

Comment: Without seeing your data it is impossible for me to help. Most likely it is mismatch between mst_ship_num on sheet and in the database. Hidden spaces, upper case v lower case etc. Go through the debug.print statements on the immediate window and check the mst_ship_num values are EXACTLY as in the database.